# What is the name of the movie where the president crash lands in a prison city?

Tags: story-identification

There was a movie that I saw maybe 10 years ago about a city in the future that is used as a prison (walls around it). Airforce One (or another plane) crash lands in the city and the protagonist of the story has to go rescue him. Some of the prisoners ran around in groups like birds.

Is that enough to identify the movie?

Answer (score 33):

[Escape from New York](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082340/)

> In the future, crime is out of control
>   and New York City is a maximum
>   security prison. Grabbing a bargaining
>   chip right out of the air, convicts
>   bring down the President's plane in
>   bad old Gotham. Gruff Snake Plissken,
>   a one-eyed lone warrior new to prison
>   life, is coerced into bringing the
>   President, and his cargo, out of this
>   land of undesirables.

Edit: There is also a sequel: [Escape From L.A.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116225/)

> Snake Plissken is once again called in by the United States government to recover a potential doomsday device from Los Angeles, now an autonomous island where undesirables are deported.

Comment: Escape from New York is a science fiction classic. Escape from LA is horrible and offensive. Definitely check out the first, and give the second a miss.

Comment: It's got a funny twist to the end but is fairly dreadful overall